# What's your Modus Operandi for solving a (programming) problem?

Tags: language-agnostic

While solving any programming problem, what is your [modus operandi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi)? How do you fix a problem?
Do you write everything you can about the observable behaviors of the bug or problem?

Take me through the mental checklist of actions you take.

(As they say - *`First, solve the problem. Then, write the code`*)

Comment: @George  Nicely revised.Thanks.

Comment: I'm torn. I voted to close that question you listed Ravi; it ought to be a community wiki, in line with other questions of that nature. It's an interesting question though.

Comment: Yes. This question already has the best answer. I'm also sure the bounty will go to Casey only for the awesome answer. But there is always hope. ;) (Not that I'm expecting a better answer)

Comment: 50 points for my Modus Operandi? I don't think so - it's worth 75 at least.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Post. Let the communiy decide. And I'll make sure you will get 100 if its worth. :)

Comment: @Ravi: I'm holding you to that promise - you know I'm right. :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Step away from the computer** and grab some paper and a pen or pencil if you prefer.

If I'm around the computer then I try to program a solution right then and there and it normally doesn't work right or it's just crap.  Pen and paper force me to think a little more.

Comment: I prefer PENCIL and paper as you can erase as needed.  But a pen and a stack of paper works as well.

Comment: I prefer whiteboard and dry erase.  I have that next to my computer at work and at home.

Comment: Bulls eye! Simple n accurate answer.

Comment: I also prefer the whiteboard. Sadly, that will disappear when we move to a new building. Instead of the nice little office I have now, I'll be in the open plan area. Not even real cubes, so there is no way to have whiteboard in my workspace. Going from a 4x8 whiteboard to pencil and paper is going to be quite an adjustment.

Comment: +1, but I like to do some coding experiments and some research before grabbing the pen&paper. It helps me know what I actually have to think about.

Answer (score 38):

First, I go to [one bicycle shop](http://www.google.com); [or another](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Once I figure nobody invented that particular bicycle,

- Figure out appropriate data structures for the domain and the problem, and then map needed algorithms for dealing with those data structures in ways you need.
- Divide and conquer. Solve subsets of the problem

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for a good answer, but I just have to say that for me it's much more fun to build the bicycle than to buy one someone else has built.  I like to have my bicycle MY way, and nobody else does it that way.

Comment: Yep. I learned that from my wife. I used to always write things from scratch, but her philosophy is, "Why re-invent the wheel?"

Comment: Get a couple of kids. Then you won't have time to re-invent bicycles :)

Comment: @David I like the bicycles that people build and then give out for free.

Comment: @David, Making the bicycle *your way* might be cool, but technically speaking, its a waste of time. You also have to spend a lot of time convincing others.. That means less programming and more work in justifying it.  I totally understand if you need to *modify* said bicycle to accommodate a new steering system however, with a plan to modify the rest at another time. 

@Tnay,
as long as you remember that beggars can't be choosers, there's plenty of awesome code out there.  Lets just hope that you understand it when it comes time to fix it!

Comment: i like to create my own bicycle bcs i prefer to fix my own bugs than those of other people

Comment: I'm with David on this one.  I'm pretty set against implementing code unless I know what it's doing and I understand my code better than I understand others'.

Comment: I prefer to build my own bicycles as well because I want to know exactly how they handle and how to quickly fix it if something breaks. I do, however, like to take inspiration from other bicycles and improve on their design. I might do some reconnaissance at a bike shop or two. I also like to add the little streamers on the end of the handlebars and bells to my bikes.

Comment: @Tnay is right.  And if you need to fix bugs and patches aren't accepted for some reason, fork!

Comment: I like to steal other people's bicycles and take them apart.

Answer (score 31):

This algorithm has never failed me:

1. **Take Action.**  Often just sitting there and being terrified or miffed by the problem will not help solve it.  Also, often, no amounting of thinking will solve the problem.  So you have to get your hands dirty and grapple with the problem head on.
2. **Test.**  Under exactly what conditions, input values or states, does the problem occur?  Make a mental model of why these particular conditions might cause the problem.  Check similar conditions that don't cause the problem.  Test enough so that you have a clear understanding of the problem.
3. **Visualise.** Put debug code in, dump variable contents, single step code whatever.  Do anything that clarifies exactly what is going on where - within the problem conditions.
4. **Simplify.**  Remove or comment code, poke values into variables, run particular functions with certain values. Try your hardest to get to the nub of the problem by cutting away the chaff or stuff that doesn't have a relevance to the problem at hand.  Copy code into a separate project and run it, if you have to, to remove dependencies.
5. **Accept.**  A great man said: "whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth".  In other words, after simplifying as much as you can, whatever is left must be the problem, no matter how bizarre it may seem at first.
6. **Logic.**  Double, triple check the logic of the problem.  Does it make sense? What would have to be true for it to make sense? Is there something you're missing?  Is your understanding of the algorithm wrong? If all else fails, re-engineer the problem away.

As an adjunct to step 3, as a last resort, I often employ the binary search method of finding wayward code.  Simply comment half the code and see if the problem disappears. If it does then it must be in that half (and vice versa).  Half the remaining code and continue.

Comment: +1 for writing an in-depth answer.

Answer (score 14):

- Google is great for searching for
  error messages and common problems. Somewhere, someone has usually encountered your problem before and found a solution.
- Pencil and paper. Pseudo Code and
  workflow diagrams.
- Talk to other developers about it. It
  really helps when you have to force
  yourself to simplify the problem for
  someone else to understand.  They may also have another angle. Sometimes it's hard to see the forest through the trees.
- Go for a walk.  Take your head out of
  the problem. Take a step back and try
  to see the bigger picture of what you
  want to achieve.  Make sure the problem you are 'trying' to solve is the one your 'need' to solve.
- A big whiteboard is great to work on. Use it to write out workflows and relationships. Talk through what is happening with another team member
- Move on.  Do something else.  Let your subconscious work on the problem.  Allow the solution to come to you.

Comment: +1 for talking a walk and letting your subconscious work on the problem. Never underestimate the effect these can have! Whiteboards are great also, but have been mentioned a lot)

Answer (score 8):

1. write down the problem
2. think very hard
3. write down the answer

Comment: +1 Good try even after seeing a +20 answer.

Comment: Um, I think Feynman's dead, so what good did his "algorithm" do him?

Comment: I don't think the algorithm killed him :P

Comment: I'm sure if Richard Feynman had a computer on his desktop his algorithm would be different.

Answer (score 8):

I can't believe no one posted this already:

**Write up your problem on StackOverflow, and let a bunch of other people solve it for you.**

Answer (score 5):

My method, something analytic-sinthetic:

1. Calm down. Take a deep breath. Focus your attention in what you're going to solve. This may include going for a walk, cleaning the whiteboard, getting scratch paper and pencils ordered, some snacks, etc. Avoid stress.
2. High level understanding of the problem. In case it is a bug, when does it happened? in what circumstances? If it is a new task, try to diverge of what results are needed. Recollect data, evidence, get acceptance descriptions, maybe documentation or a talk with someone that knows about the issue.
3. Setup the test playground. Try to feel happy with the tools needed. Use the data collected in the previous step to automate something, hopefully the bug if that's the case, some failing tests otherwise.
4. Start sinthesizing, summarizing what you know, reflecting that on code. Executing once and once more. If you are not happy with the results, return to step two with renewed ideas, diverge more: maybe apply tools (in order of cost) that helped before, i.e. divide and conquer, debug, multithread, dissassemble, profile, static analysis tools, metrics, etc. Get in this loop until you can isolate the problem and pass the [over the phone test](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/phone-test/).
5. Now it's time to fix it but you have all the tools set up. It won't be so much trouble. Start writing code, apply refactoring, enjoy describing your solution in the docs.
6. Get someone to try your solution. She can eventually get you to step 2 but that's ok. Refine your solution and redeploy.

Comment: +1 for the over the phone test.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting this as fixing a bug, not a design problem.

Isolate the problem. Does it always occur? Does it occur only the first time run on a set of new data? Does it occur with specific values, but not with others?

Is the system generating any error message that appear related to the problem? Verify that the error messages are not generated when the problem does not occur.

Has anything been changed recently? Those are likely places to start looking.

Identify the gap between what I know is working (e.g. I can start up the app and attempt to do a query) and what I know is not working (e.g. it gives me an error instead of the expected results). Find an intermediate point in the code where it seems possible to look for a problem (does this contain valid data at this point?). This allows me to isolate the problem on one side or the other of the point I looked.

Read the stack traces. If you have a stack trace, find the first line that mentions in-house code. The problem is not in your libraries. Maybe it will turn out to be, but just forget about that possibly first. The error is in your code. It's not a bug in java, it's not a bug in apache commons HTTP client, it's in code written in your organization.

Think. Come up with something the system could be doing that can cause the symptoms you see. Find a way to validate whether that is what the system is doing.

No possibility the bug is in your code? Google for anything you can think of related. Maybe it is a bug in the library, or poor documentation leading you to use it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Logic.

Break the problem down, use your own brain and knowledge of each component of the system to determine exactly what is happening and why; then on the basis of this you will discover where the problem isn't, and hence determine where it must be.

Answer (score 2):

I stop working on it until tomorrow.  I usually solve my problem in the shower the next day.  I find stepping away from the issue, and allowing my brain to clear, allows a fresh perspective on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Answer these three questions in this order:

**Q1:  What is the desired output?**
I don't care if this is a napkin with scribble on it. I want something tangible that shows me what the end result is supposed to look like. If I don't get at least this far then I stop.
**Q2:  What is the input?**
I find out what data I have coming in. Where this data is coming from from. What formulas I may need. What dependencies there might be on **A** happening before **B**. What permissions if any are necessary to get this data. I then ask Question 3.

**Q3:  Is there enough input to create the output?**
If the answer is **No** then I go back to **Q2** and get more input from whoever can give it to me.
For very large problems I break them down in **Phases** and apply **Q1 Q2** and **Q3** to each phase.

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase Douglas Adams, programming is easy. You only need to stare at a blank screen until your forehead bleeds. For people who are squeamish about their foreheads, my ideal architect-and-build for the bigger problems would go something like this. (For smaller problems, like George Jempty I can only recommend [Feynman's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1645768/revisions).)

What I write is couched in an on-site business setting but there are analogues in open-source or distributed teams. And I can't pretend that every, or even most, projects pan out this way. This is just the series of events that I dream about, and occasionally come to pass.

1. Get advanced, concise warning of what the problem is likely to look like. This is *not* the full, final meeting, but an informal discussion. Uncertainty in certain specification details is fine, as long as the client (or manager) is honest. Then take a piece of paper or text editor, and try to condense what you've learned down to five essential points, and then try to condense *those* to a single sentence. *Be happy you can picture the core problem(s) to be solved without referencing any of your documentation.*
2. Think about it for maybe a couple of hours, maybe playing with code and prototyping, but not with a view to the full architecture: you should even do other stuff, if you've time, or go for a walk. It's great if you can learn about a job an hour before home time in order to deliver a decision around midday the next day, so you get to sleep on it. Spend your time looking at potential libraries, frameworks, data standards. Try to tie together at least two languages or resources (say, Javascript on PHP-generated HTML; or get a Python stub talking RPC to a web service). *Flesh out the core problems; zoom in on the details; zoom out to make sure the whole shape is still distinct and makes sense.*
3. Send any questions to the client or manager well in advance of a meeting to discuss both the problem and your proposed solution. Invite as many stakeholders and your programming peers along as is convenient (and as your manager is happy with.) Explain the problem back to them, as you see it, then propose your solution. *Explain as much as you can; pitch the technical details at your audience, but also let your explanations fill in more details in your own mental model.*
4. Iterate on 2 and 3 until everyone is happy. Happiness is domain-specific. Your industry might require UML diagrams and line-item quotations, or it might be happy with something jotted on a whiteboard with an almost invisible drywipe marker. *Make sure everyone has the same expectations of what you're about to build.*
5. When your client or manager is happy for you to start, clear everything. Close Twitter, instant messenger, IRC and email for an hour or two. Start with the overall structure as you see it. Drop some of your prototype code in and see if it feels right. If it doesn't, change the structure as early as possible. But most of all make sure your colleagues give you a couple of hours of space. Try not to fight fires in this time. *Begin with a good heart and cheer, and interest in the project. When you're bogged down later on you'll be glad of the clarity that came out of those first few hours.*

How your programming proceeds from there depends on what it actually is, and what tasks the finished code needs to perform. And how you ultimately architect your code, and what external resources you use, will always be dictated by your experience, preference and domain knowledge. But give your project and its stakeholder team the most hopeful, most exciting and most engaged start you can.

Answer (score 1):

Pencil, paper and a whiteboard.  If you need more organization, use a tool like [MindManager](http://www.mindjet.com/products/mindmanager-8-win/overview).

Answer (score 1):

Andy Hunt's [Pragmatic Thinking and Learning](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ahptl/pragmatic-thinking-and-learning) has a lot to say on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Question: How do you eat an elephant?

Answer: One bite at a time.

Comment: Sorry,I am a vegetarian.

Comment: Sorry, that was not intended literally. Any overwhelmingly large task, take it one small piece at a time.

Comment: @ Cyclon Cat Oh,dear.I was just joking.You don't have to take it seriously.

Comment: In that case, I won't take it seriously!

Comment: but you've to kill the elephant first. That can be tough.

Comment: This remembers me that Sheldon doesn't gets irony. (Big bang theory)

Comment: refer to George Orwell's "Shooting an Elephant": http://www.online-literature.com/orwell/887/

Comment: That reminds me of Q: How do you get down from an elephant? A: You don't; you get down from a duck.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I like using for really big projects is to get into a room with a whiteboard and a pile of square Post-it Notes.

Write your tasks on the Post-it Notes then start sticking them on the whiteboard.

As you go, you can replace tasks that are too big with multiple notes.

You can shift notes around to change the order that the tasks happen in.

Use different colours to indicate different information; I sometimes use a different colour to indicate stuff that we need to do more research on.

This is a great technique for working with a team. Everybody can see the big picture and can contribute in a highly interactive way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a gross oversimplification:

[image: CONCEIVE. PLAN. EXECUTE.]

But really, this holds 100% true.

**CONCEIVE**

What are you without an idea? You may have a problem, but first you must define it more explicitly. You have a frozen pizza that you want to eat. You need to *cook* that pizza! In programming, this is usually your brainstorming session for coming up with a solution from the hip. Here you decide what your approach is.

**PLAN**

Well, of course you need to cook that pizza! But HOW! Will you use the oven? No. *Too easy*. You want to build a solar cooker, so you can eat that frozen pizza anywhere that the sun grants you power to do so. This is your design phase. This is your pencil and paper phase. This is where you start to form a cohesive, step-by-step method to implementation.

**EXECUTE**

Well, you are going to build a solar oven to cook your frozen pizza; you've *decided*. NOW **DO IT**. Write code. Test. Commit. Refactor. Commit.

Comment: Courage Wolf makes me confident!

Answer (score 1):

1. I think about it. I take anywhere from a couple minutes to a few weeks to mull over the problem and develop a general plan of attack.
2. Hammer out an initial solution. This solution is probably half-baked and one or more aspects may not work.
3. Refine that solution. Keep working on the problem till i have something that solves the problem.
4. (and this may be done at any step in the process) Ask questions on stack overflow to clear up any difficulties i'm having at the moment.

Comment: +1 for point#2 "This solution is probably half-baked"

Answer (score 1):

One of my ex-colleagues had a unique *Modus Operandi*. Whenever faced with a hard programming problem (e.g. [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or some kind of non-standard [optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem)) he would get stoned on weed, claiming his ability to visualize complex state (such as that of recursive function doing operations on set passed on the stack) was greatly improved. The only difficulty, the next day he could not understand his own code. So eventually I showed him TDD and he has quit smoking...

Comment: Wow. Yet another reason TDD is bad ...

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to a bug rather than building a project from scratch (but even then it could do both if reworded a bit):

1. **Context**: What is the problem at hand? What is it preventing, doing wrong, or not doing?
2. **Control**: What variables (in the wide sense of the word) are involved? Can the problem be reproduced?
3. **Hypothesise**: With enough data on what is occurring or required, it is possible to hypothesise, that is, to draw a mental image of the problem in question.
4. **Evaluate**: How much effort, cost, etc, will the correction require? Determine if it's a show stopper or a minor irritant. At this point, it may be too early to tell, but even that is a form of evaluation. This will allow prioritisation.
5. **Plan**: How will the problem be approached? Does it require specifications? If so, do them first.
6. **Execute**: A.K.A. The fun part.
7. **Test**: A.K.A. The not-so-fun-part.

Repeat to satisfaction. Finally:

**Feedback**: how did it come to be this way? What lead us here? Could this have been prevented, and if so, how?

EDIT:

Really summarised, stop, analyse, act.

Answer (score 1):

I write it on a piece of paper and start with my horrible class diagram or flowchart. Then I  write it on sticky notes to break it down to "TO DO's".

1 sticky note = 1 task. 1 dumped sticky note = 1 finished task. This works really well for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Add the problem to StackOverflow, wait about 5-10 minutes and you usually have a brilliant solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Every problem I've ever had to solve on a computer has had something to do with solving a task in the real world.  Therefore, I've learned to look at how I would accomplish something in the real world and map that to the computer problem.

---

**Example:**

I need to keep track of my student's grades and come up with a final grade that is an average of all the grades throughout the year?

Well, I'd save the grades in a log (database) and I'd have a page for every student (Field StudentID) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Related question that may be useful:

[Helpful points of view, concepts or ways to think about problems every newbie should know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187722/helpful-points-of-view-concepts-or-ways-to-think-about-problems-every-newbie-sho/1504911#1504911)

Answer (score 0):

I always take a problem to a blog first. Stackoverflow would be a good place to start. Why waste your time re-inventing the wheel when someone else may have already solved a similar problem in the past? If anything you will get some good ideas to solve it yourself.

Comment: Because the wheel usually sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [the scientific method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method):

1. Based on the available information about the programming problem I come up with a [hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothesis) about what the reason could be.
2. Then I design / think up an experiment that will reject or confirm the hypothesis. This could be observing something in a debugger or screen/file output. Or changing the program slightly.
3. If the hypothesis is rejected then repeat 1. The information gathered in 2. may help in coming up with a new hypothesis.
4. If the hypothesis is confirmed then the hypothesis may be refined/become more specific (repeat 1.). Or it may already be clear what the problem is.

This directed way of find the problem is much more effective than changing things at random, observe what happens and try to (inappropriately) use statistics.

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned truth tables! But that's probably because they're usually only mildly helpful ;) (although your mileage may vary) I used one for the first time yesterday in my 8 years of programming.

Diagramming on whiteboards or paper have always been very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with very weird bugs. Like this: [JPA stops working after redeploy in glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557815/jpa-stops-working-after-redeploy-in-glassfish)

I start from scratch. Make a new project. Does it work? Yes. Start to recreate the components of my app one piece of a time. DB. Check. Deploy. Check. Until it breaks. Continue until it breaks. If it never breaks. Ok. You just recreated your entire app. Discard of the old one. When it breaks. You pinpointed the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think - what am i looking for?
2. What method best solves this problem?
3. Implement it with solid logic - no code
4. Pseudo code
5. code a rough cut
6. execute

Answer (score 0):

These is my prioritized methods

1. Analyse
   a. Try to find the source of your problem
   b. Define desired outcome
   c. Brainstorm about solutions
2. Try on error (If I dont want to analyse)
3. Google a bit around
   a. Of course, look around on stackoverflow
4. When you get mad, walk away from pc for a cup of coffee
5. When you still mad after 10 cups of coffee, Go sleep a night to think about the problem

**GOLDEN TIP**
**Never give up. Persistence will always win**