# JPA stops working after redeploy in glassfish

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

Using oracle xe with glassfish and eclipselink. Problems with persisting objects arise. After fresh restart of glassfish app works ok. If app is recompiled and redeployed via admin interface. Persisting objects stops working. The error is:

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-17041: (no message for error) 1
Error Code: 17041

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Pasted logs http://pastebin.com/qC01ztkx

Comment: and nothing else in the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a reference to ojdbc6.jar in my app. I have removed the reference and supplied glassfish with ojdbc6.jar by copying said jar to glassfish/lib

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to always restart the server after deploying. You can run out of perm gen space, and have other weird issues as well.

Since you're saying it works after restarting, I would chalk it up to that.

Comment: It takes almost a full minute to restart glassfish. I would really like to avoid that as that would make dev a pita.

Comment: You might figure out a way past this issue but then it'll just be something else. I strongly suggest restarting after deploying.